# XCodeのストーリーボードで青い線表示

Tags: xcode, storyboard

XCodeのストーリーボードで青い線が表示されるようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「Title」とか「duration_text」やセルの周りにある青い線です。
特に困ることはないのですが、消して作業したいなと思っています。
おそらく何かショートカットを触ってしまったと思いますが、消し方をご存知の方、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

追記：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

全てのチェックを外してみたのですが、消えませんでした。

Comment: 承認じゃなく編集して追記するのには何か意味がありますか？解決したのであれば承認の方をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553526/how-to-hide-blue-line-covering-views-in-xib-storyboard-in-xcode-7-2

これですね。

Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles

のチェックをはずせば消えます。

Comment: Show Bounds Rectanglesのチェックは外してみましたが、消えません。

Comment: あら。残念です。XcodeやMacの再起動するとどうでしょう？

Comment: Xcodeの再起動で消えました。

Comment: よかったです。ここの該当部分のチェックは青線と関わりがあるので、おそらく何かの調子がわるくXcodeを再起動しないと反映されなかったものと思います。